# how to share data(like pandas dataframe) between separate processes( Not parent-child relationship) in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shared-memory

I am now creating a financial analysis program with financial data using python.The data was stored in a database using MySQL. I need to load the data from the database whenever I debug or add a new module. But the data is so big that it takes very long to load the data. So I want to write a program that loads data into memory only once and allows multiple processes to share it.The Python library multiprocess seems to allow sharing only if it is a parent child relationship.
I want the process to be able to share data with completely separate Python processes, not parent-child relationships. I created shared memory using sysv_ipc, but I could only share data in byte format, and pandas dataframe could not use shared memory.

Comment: Have you thought about using a client server architecture? Where I work we did something similar this way.